# Parametric solution of the PDE $-yu_x+xu_y=0,\:u(x,x^2)=x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the parametric form of the solution of the following PDE using method of characteristics: $$-yu_x+xu_y=0\qquad u(x,x^2)=x^3$$

I assume that $(x,y)$ are functions of a parameter, say, $t$, i.e. $(x(t), y(t))$. In that case, the chain rule gives

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{d x}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

Comparing the equations, we need to solve the ODEs to find the characteristic curves.

$$\frac{du}{dt}=0,\quad\frac{d x}{dt}=-y \qquad\&\quad\frac{d y}{dt}=x$$

I get the solution, $x(t)=C_{11}\cos(t)+C_{12}\sin(t)$, $y(t)=C_{21}\cos(t)+C_{22}\sin(t)$ and $u(t)=C$.

Using initial conditions $x(0,s)=s$, $y(0,s)=s^2$ and $u(0,s)=s^3$ we get, $x(t)=s\cos(t)+C_{12}\sin(t)$,  $y(t)=s^2\cos(t)+C_{22}\sin(t)$ and $u(t)=s^3$. But how to remove $C_{12},C_{22}$ constants without initial conditions?

I noticed they used one more extra parameter, $s$. Why it was needed? Like why, we re-interpret the $x(t)$ as $x(t,s)$?

I am new to this method. It will be a great help if anyone provide some insight along the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two parameters are needed because $u$ is a surface. I suggest you have a look at the Wikipedia page for the method of characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @K.defaoite I am reading the Wiki article. Hope I will resolve the confusion. Okay, $u$ is surface, but why $x(0,s)$ introduced? Isn't $x$ expressed only by $t$ variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
y=-\frac{dx}{dt}=C_{11}\sin(t)-C_{12}\cos(t)
$$
which eliminates the other two constants, as $C_{21}=-C_{12}$ and $C_{22}=C_{11}$.

The aim is to find the value $u$ for a given point $(x,y)$ in the domain. The characteristic curve says that $u$ is constant on the circle
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y}
=
\pmatrix{\cos(t)&-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\cos(t)}
\pmatrix{x_0\\y_0}
$$
The initial condition demands that $x_0=s$, $y_0=s^2$. So one has to find $s$ and $t$ so that the parametrization matches the point. From being on a circle centered at the origin we know that the angle $t$ can be eliminated by considering the radius
$$
x^2+y^2=s^2+s^4\implies s^2=\pm\sqrt{\frac14+x^2+y^2}-\frac12
\\
\implies s = \pm\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac14+x^2+y^2}-\frac12}.
$$
As that still gives 2 real intersection points with different values for $u$, the domain has to be further restricted, probably to $x\ge 0$.

Comment: I guess the lecture note miss that restriction @LutzLehmann. And thanks for your help. I still couldn't grasp the line, **"So one has to find $s$ and $t$ so that the parametrization matches the point."** Could you explain it a little more? Like **which points** you are pointing, as $u$ is constant on the whole circle. I guess you pointing **find the value $u$ for a given point $(x,y)$ in the domain**

Comment: The selected $(x,y)$ define a circle. The location of the point on the circle is given by the angle. However, in the formulation above, and conceptually, this angle is relative to the boundary point. The relevant boundary point is the intersection of the parabola $y=x^2$ with the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$. But there are two such intersection points.

Comment: Or generally, as a forward problem from $(s,t)$ to $(x,y)$, the parameter $s$ selects the boundary point $(x_0(s),y_0(s))$ with value $z_0(s)$. The Lagrange ODE system then propagates this along a characteristic curve, from $(x,y,z)(0)=(x_0(s),y_0(s),z_0(s))$ to $(x,y,u(x,y))=(x,y,z)(t)$. The task is to solve an inverse problem here or an implicit (BVP) problem in general if $u$ is not constant for this forward problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$-yu_x+xu_y=0$$
The charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $du=0$
$$u=c_1$$
which is an obvious particular solution of the PDE.

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}$:
$$x^2+y^2=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE$\quad c_1=F(c_2)\quad$is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=F(x^2+y^2)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function until no boundary condition is taken into account.

The most interesting part of the problem is to find the particular solution(s) which satisfy the condition $u(x,x^2)=x^3$.
$$u(x,x^2)=F(x^2+(x^2)^2)=x^3$$
Let $X=x^2+(x^2)^2$.
Solving the quadratic eq. $(x^2)^2+(x^2)-X=0$ for $(x^2)$ then for $x$ :

$x=\pm \left(\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4X}}{2} \right)^{1/2}\quad$ with
$\quad X(0)=0\quad\implies\quad x=\pm \left(\frac{-1+ \sqrt{1+4X}}{2} \right)^{1/2}$

$$F(X)=x^3\quad\implies\quad\begin{cases}
F(X)=+\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4X}}{2} \right)^{3/2}\quad \text{if}\quad x>0 \\
F(X)=0\quad \text{if}\quad x=0 \\
F(X)=-\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4X}}{2} \right)^{3/2}\quad \text{if}\quad x<0
\end{cases}$$

Now the function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X= x^2+y^2$ :

$$\begin{cases}
u(x,y)=\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}}{2} \right)^{3/2}\quad \text{if}\quad x>0 \\
u(x,y)=0\quad \text{if}\quad x=0 \\
u(x,y)=-\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}}{2} \right)^{3/2}\quad \text{if}\quad x<0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Aha, nice(+1) @JJacquelin. I am reading so many answer of your today.  But I get confused in the name **charpit-Lagrange characteristic** vs **method of characteristic**. Are they same? What I understand, characteristic method find parameterized curves where the PDE "collapses" to an equivalent set of ODEs on the surface. But still need some time to grasp the PDE concept. Thanks again